# Flask can't find the config module in parent directory

Tags: python, web-applications, flask

I'm basing myself on the structure of a web app I found up on github, [here](https://github.com/nickjj/build-a-saas-app-with-flask).

My project's structure looks like this:

```
~/Learning/flask-celery $ tree
.
├── config
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── settings.py
├── docker-compose.yml
├── Dockerfile
├── requirements.txt
└── web
    ├── app.py
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── static
    └── templates
        └── index.html
```

I want my Flask app in `web/app.py` to load the settings in the `config` module, as I saw in the githug project linked above.

Here's how I'm instantiating the Flask app in `web/app.py`:

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, session, flash, redirect, url_for, jsonify

[...]

app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)

app.config.from_object('config.settings')
app.config.from_pyfile('settings.py')

[...]
```

The issue I'm getting is:

```
root@0e221733b3d1:/usr/src/app# python3 web/app.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/werkzeug/utils.py", line 427, in import_string
    module = __import__(module_name, None, None, [obj_name])
ImportError: No module named 'config'
[...]
```

Obviously, Flask can't find the `config` module in the parent directory, which makes sens to me, but I don't understand how the linked project I'm basing myself on is successfully loading the module with the same tree structure and Flask config code.

In these circumstances, how can I get Flask to load the `config` module?

Answer (score 3):

Without adding the config directory to your path your Python package will not be able to see it.

Your code can only access what is in `web` by the looks of it.

You can add the config directory to the package like so:

```
import os
import sys
import inspect

currentdir = os.path.dirname(
    os.path.abspath(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())))
parentdir = os.path.dirname(currentdir)
sys.path.insert(0, parentdir)
```

Then you should be able to import config.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll give this a try and it looks like it should work, but I'm curious as to how the linked github project got it working then? I thought `instance_relative_config=True` would mean that it would look in my root.

Comment: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/config/#instance-folders not sure why yours instant working probably had to do with how its being run.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone finds themselves looking at this question from years ago, it is possible to load the config file in the project structure above like this:

`app.config.from_pyfile('../config/settings.py')`

This will work when starting the app using `flask run`